# 101 rep but can't post answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers

I have the automatic 101 rep coming from StackOverflow but I can't post an answer to [How do you breed an Opal Dragon in Dragonvale?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86425/how-do-you-breed-an-opal-dragon-in-dragonvale) as it's protected.

The text I see is this: I am logged in and I have refreshed the page, using iOS5 on an iPad

```
protected by agent86♦ 2 hours ago

This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers 
by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on 
this site.
```

Or should I take the last sentence more literally, and my 101 counts for nothing on this site?

Answer (score 8):

This is intended, the last sentence is meant to be explicit as to remove any confusion.

We previously had issues with network users with association bonuses and 0 involvement with a site causing issues, so at least 1-2 upvotes on the site is the barrier we set on protected questions.  This is the *only* place I can think of where we actually lock privileges down to reputation earned *on this site only*.

Comment: I had the same confusion on a different question where I had to answer in a comment. I can't get rep points for comments so I can't get the 10 points needed. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112728/unable-to-open-any-save-games-after-patch. @SevenSidedDice was kind to update his answer with my comment but that's not going to help me get rep and answer other questions. Why are so many questions being protected on this site?

Comment: I think I know the answer for a great question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/256801/137332
Great for me as terminology nuances are my hobby.
I happen to also be a programmer.
However I can't answer that question because my association bonus doesn't count.
I have checked other unaswered questions on this site, but I can't answer them as I'm not up to date with modern video games. I don't see a good way for me to earn 10 reputation on this site. *I could answer that one because it's not about video games.* Is there a viable way for me to post an answer there?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109117/can-the-protect-feature-be-made-to-block-101-users-as-well), [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)!

I have, however, unprotected the question if you'd like to try again.

Try to actually post an answer, though, unlike *practically everyone else who posts on a dragonvale question, sigh...*

Comment: Thanks, I have.